# Выключатели света

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Есть [задача](https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?chapterid=2838#1). Её суть в следующем, вводятся 4 выключателя(0 - выключено, 1 - включено) и есть условие, что свет включается если включены хотя бы два выключателя и они расположены не рядом друг с другом.

Я написал вот такой код:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a,b,c,d;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    int res = 1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + d;
    if(res == 1001 || res == 1010 || res == 0101 ){
        cout << "YES";
    }
    else{
        cout << "NO";
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть не так. Не проходит 3 теста

Comment: 0101 - это в восьмиричной системе, просто пишите 101

Comment: *что может быть не так* 1101, например, тоже "свет включается". В задании написано "хотя бы два", а не "строго два".

Comment: @Maksim, решение Harry прошло тест?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, да прошло

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,d;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    int res = 1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + d;
    if (a+b+c+d < 2) { cout << "NO"; return 0; }

    if (a+b+c+d == 2 && (res == 1010 || res == 101 || res == 1001)) { cout << "YES"; return 0; }

    if (a+b+c+d >2) { cout << "YES"; return 0; }
    cout << "NO";
}
```

Важно, чтоб *имелись* два не рядом, а не *не было двух рядом*.

Специально для @user7860670:

```
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,d;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    cout << ((d*b+d*a+c*a) ? "YES" : "NO");
}
```

Comment: 1111 - вернет YES?

Comment: Столько условий и лишних действий, что было бы проще перебрать правильные варианты.

Comment: @user7860670 OK, только для вас. Это устраивает?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Ну а куда ж оно денется?...

Comment: @Harry, интересно) А как бы формулировалась задача, если бы было 6 выключателей и 101010 - это приемлимо, а 101100 - нет?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Включены хотя бы два выключателя; при этом никакие смежные выключатели не находятся во включенном состоянии.

Comment: @Harry, у меня непонятка возникла к чему применять операцию "не рядом с друг другом" - к "двум выключателям" или "хотя бы к двум выключателям".

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Я думаю, судя по результатам, к "хотя бы двум включенным".

Answer (score 0):

Задача сводится к нахождению последовательности включенный выключать - один или более выключателей в произвольном состоянии - включенный выключатель. Когда входящая последовательность короткая, то вполне можно прибегнуть к простому перебору, как то предлагают в другом ответе. Однако более толковый метод - создание конечного автомата. Для данной задачи он будет состоять из 4 состояний:

- 1 Начало - ожидание первого включенного выключателя - если попадается включенный выключатель, то переходим в состояние 2.
- 2 Пропуск выключателя - независимо от попавшегося выключателя переходим в состояние 3.
- 3 Ожидание второго включенного выключателя - если попадается включенный выключатель, то переходим в состояние 0.
- 0 Конец - искомая последовательность найдена, состояние больше не меняется.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    constexpr unsigned char sm[4][2]{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 0}};
    unsigned char state{1};
    for (auto values_count{4}; values_count; --values_count)
    {
        unsigned int value;
        ::std::cin >> value;
        state = sm[state][value];
    }
    ::std::cout << (state ? "NO" : "YES");
    return 0;
}
```

Стоит отметить, что этот метод не требует хранения входящей последовательности и работает независимо от ее длины. Также при достижении конечного состояния входящую последовательность можно дальше не читать.